# Passing a variable that holds JSON acts differently when in '{}' - why?

Tags: node.js, json

I am writing a CLI application with Nodejs. The user sees a list of items and selects one that they want to be removed. The list they see is generated via a JSON file. The JSON file has one property with an array of actions:

```
{    

 "actionList":[
     "Action 1","Action 2","Action 3","Action 5","Action 6"]    
}
```

Their input triggers an item to be removed and the file to be re-written with the updated list with `fs.writeFileSync`.

### **Question**

When I write to the file WITHOUT `{}`, it writes the array to the JSON file without the property `actionList`:

The code:

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, "./.todo.json"),
    JSON.stringify( actionList , null, 4)
  );
```

The result:

```
     ["Action 1","Action 2","Action 3","Action 5","Action 6"]
```

But when I use {} around actionList, I get the JSON file with the `actionList` property.

The code:

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, "./.todo.json"),
    JSON.stringify({ actionList }, null, 4)
  );
```

The result:

```
"actionList":[
         "Action 2","Action 3","Action 5","Action 6"]    
    }
```

What exactly is the {} doing in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ actionList }` is the same as `{ "actionList": actionList }`

It is ES6 property shorthand.

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015

Another example: https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

So the `{}` adds another layer around your object, with a key `"actionList"` and the value of the variable `actionList`.